# Why is my app crashing shortly after termination?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In my iOS app, I have several Firebase event listeners in place as the user performs different functions. I am encountering an issue where the app crashes (only sometimes) specifically when the user terminates it by double-tapping the home button and swiping up. In the applicationWillTerminate function of AppDelegate.swift, I simply remove all registered event listeners:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    Home.globalEvents = []
    removeListeners()
}

private func removeListeners()
{
    UserService.userEventListener?.remove()
    UserService.friendIDListener?.remove()
    UserService.groupListener?.remove()
    UserService.postListener?.remove()
    Home.requestListener?.remove()
    Home.eventsListener?.remove()
    Home.inviteListener?.remove()
    Home.requestCount = 0
    Home.inviteCount = 0
    Home.publicEventListener?.remove()
    Home.privateEventListener?.remove()
    ProfileFinder.requestListener?.remove()
}
```

This gives me the error message:
"Assertion failure in auto FSTLocalStore::releaseQuery:::(anonymous class)::operator()() const()"

Can anyone clue me in as to why what I'm doing is problematic? Thanks.